# Is there a better way in Emacs Lisp to print the list of monospace fonts in a separate buffer?

Tags: fonts

Is there a better way in Emacs Lisp to print the list of monospace fonts in a separate buffer?

I found out the following Emacs Lips code in a gist on Github:

```
(defun font-is-mono-p (font-family)
  ;; with-selected-window
  (let ((wind (selected-window))
        m-width l-width)
   (with-current-buffer "*Monospace Fonts*"
     (set-window-buffer (selected-window) (current-buffer))
     (text-scale-set 4)
     (insert (propertize "l l l l l" 'face `((:family ,font-family))))
     (goto-char (line-end-position))
     (setq l-width (car (posn-x-y (posn-at-point))))
     (newline)
     (forward-line)
     (insert (propertize "m m m m m" 'face `((:family ,font-family) italic)))
     (goto-char (line-end-position))
     (setq m-width (car (posn-x-y (posn-at-point))))
     (eq l-width m-width))))

(defun compare-monospace-fonts ()
  "Display a list of all monospace font faces."
  (interactive)
  (pop-to-buffer "*Monospace Fonts*")
  (erase-buffer)
  (dolist (font-family (font-family-list))
    (when (font-is-mono-p font-family)
      (let ((str font-family))
        (newline)
        (insert
         (propertize (concat "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1 l; 0 O o ("
                             font-family ")\n") 'face `((:family ,font-family)))
         (propertize (concat "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog 1 l; 0 O o ("
                             font-family ")\n") 'face `((:family ,font-family) italic)))))))
```

The way it tries to find out if a font is mono-spaced is to print some lines and check for their length as far as I can see:

[image]

But is there a better way, e.g. to **filter out** only the mono spaced fonts to begin with, I mean without relying on actually printing strings in that font and comparing the width of the display. I mean by using some font specification, etc. I read https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Low_002dLevel-Font.html, but it doesn't mention anything about "monospace" (unlike https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Fonts.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems working:

```el
(seq-filter (lambda (font)
              (when-let ((info (font-info font)))
                (string-match-p "spacing=100" (aref info 1))))
            (font-family-list))

;; =>

("Andale Mono"
 "Courier"
 "Courier New"
 "GB18030 Bitmap"
 "Input"
 "Menlo"
 "Monaco"
 "PT Mono"
 "Source Code Pro"
 "Apple Braille"
 "Apple Color Emoji")
```

the above produces the same result as macOS's Font Book.app:

[image: fixed-width fonts]

I am not a font expert and `spacing=100` is from by https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/363365/command-to-list-all-monospace-fonts-known-to-fontconfig/363368.

Comment: I've just tried your code in the `*scratch*` buffer of my Emacs 27.0.50 on MS Windows 10, and it returned `nil`. Weird. I'm trying to understand why.

Answer (score 2):

Small modification of @xuchunyang's answer for Windows, Emacs 26:

```
(require 'subr-x)
(seq-filter (lambda (font)
              (when-let ((info (font-info font)))
                (string-match-p "-mono-" (aref info 0))))
            (font-family-list))
```